# How to compare and change the array of object value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays of objects and want to compare the name and value of them.

```
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Peter',
    value: null
  }
]

const array2 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: '0'
  }
]
```

If property `name` array2 exists on array1 then change the value of name with '0' else do nothing.

The result I expect is :

```
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "value": "0"
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "value": null
]
```

Can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far ? , please paste your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `forEach()` loop for that:

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Peter',
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    value: null
  }
]

const array2 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: '0'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    value: '0'
  }
]

array2.forEach((item2) => {
  array1.forEach((item1) => {
     if(item1.name === item2.name){
       item1.value = item2.value;
     }
  });
});
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: by answering this question, you are solving Ras homework, he did not even provide what he has tried

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Ras glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

its simple :

```
array1.forEach(record1 => {
  array2.forEach(record2 => {
    if (record1.name === record2.name) {
      record1.value = "0";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: by answering this question, you are solving Ras homework, he did not even provide what he has tried

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `map` the first array and use `find`.
Please note this version of the code won't alter/mutate `array1`'s content.

```js
const array1 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: 'Peter',
    value: null
  }
];

const array2 = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    value: '0'
  }
];

const result = array1.map(item1 => {
  const newItem = {...item1}
  if(array2.find(item2 => item2.name === item1.name)) {
    newItem.value = 0;
  } 
  return newItem;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple:

you can user the below code :

```
array2.forEach(
                function(parent){

                    array1.find(function(child)
                    {
                        if(child.name==parent.name){
                            child.value=0;

                        }
                    })

                    }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const array1 = [
{
    name: 'John',
    value: null
},
{
    name: 'Peter',
    value: null
},
{
    name: 'Mike',
    value: null
}
]

const array2 = [
{
    name: 'John',
    value: '0'
},
{
    name: 'Mike',
    value: '0'
}
]


var array = array1.map(x=>{
    if(array2.some(function (value) { return value.name === x.name })){
        x.value = 0;
    }
    return x;
})
```